# What are the good practices on data history keeping through an workflow?

Tags: workflow, versioning, database-versioning

At our team, we need to keep record of data through an workflow. At each step, when the data changes, we don't want to lose its previous state because if the workflow takes a step back, that previous state must be restored.

What I ask is, what are the best practices on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Here, I found a pdf presentation and a website for best practices to improve your current workflow data recording systems and managements.

[The PDF presentation](http://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFAQFjAA&url=http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/50f1c01b-972d-2c10-3d9d-90887014fafb?overridelayout=true&ei=NKUYUPWiDsTF0QX-94D4Cw&usg=AFQjCNEoMlZv-8XO5CpVd6ht5GaeLsTPfw)

[The website](http://www.google.com.sa/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CFQQFjAC&url=http://www.wf4ever-project.org/wiki/display/docs/Workflow%2bDesign%2bBest%2bPractices&ei=NKUYUPWiDsTF0QX-94D4Cw&usg=AFQjCNHZkYAZCUw9Hvcud15jB_v8fhPBvw)

Though it will take some time for you to browse through, your efforts will be worth it. Hope this would solve your problem.
:)

regards,

Ivisire